# Mean square displacement of a 1d random walk in python

Tags: python, tracking, particles, random-walk

I'd like to calculate the mean square displacement at all times of a 1d trajectory. I'm a novice programmer, so I've attempted it from a simulated random walk.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate random walk
path = np.zeros(60)
position = 0
for i in range(1, path.size):
    move = np.random.randint(0, 2)
    if move == 0: position += -1
    else: position += 1
    path[i] = position

# returns a vector of MSDs from a given path
def calcMSD(data):
    msd = np.zeros(data.size - 1)
    for i in range(1, data.size):
        squareddisplacements = (data[i:] - data[:data.size - i])**2
        msd[i - 1] = squareddisplacements.mean()
    return msd

msd = calcMSD(path)
plt.plot(msd)
plt.show()
```

Have I implemented this correctly? Any and all advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "walk"?

Comment: The path generation part looks fine. I am not convinced by `calcMSD`. What exactly are you trying to calculate? You are calculating it from a single path, don't you want to average over a bunch of paths? I just do not know the objective here, would be best if you explained that or posted a link to whatever calculation you are trying to replicate. Also, it is likely you are missing a square root as in `msd[i - 1] = np.sqrt(squareddisplacements.mean())` and possibly a division by 'i'? again really depends on what you are trying to calc

Comment: @piterbarg Thanks for you response. I'm trying to calculate the average squared distance from the starting position at every time interval. So if I had 60 timepoints, I'd first calculate if for time intervals of  size 1, then of size 2, then all the way to size 60. At 60 there is only 1 step of that size, so it would just calculate the distance from ending point to the starting point. For example, if p(t) gives you position as a function of time, then what I'm trying to calculate at t = 1 would be:

 [p(1) - p(0))**2 + (p(2) - p(1))**2 + … + (p(n) - p(n - 1))**2] / n

Comment: @Luke It looks to me that your code does exactly that. Your code can be simplified a bit. Eg your path loop can be simply `for i in range(1, path.size):    path[i] = path[i-1] + 2*np.random.randint(0, 2)-1`. Also in `calcMSD` function, `data[:data.size - i]` can be written in a more Pythonic way as `data[:- i]`. otherwise looks good to me

Answer (score 1):

## Mean Squared Displacement

### Definition of mean squared displacement

To make sure we are agreeing on the definition, the mean squared displacement (MSD) is the mean of the squared distance from origin of a collection of particles (in our case, walkers) at a specific step.

Since we are in 1D, the distance is simply the absolute position : distance at time t = | path[t] |

To get the MSD at step t, we must take all the squared positions at step t, then take the mean of the resulting array.

That means : `MSD at step t == (path[:, t]**2).mean()` (the element-wise squaring makes it useless to take the absolute values)

`path[:, t]` means here : the positions of each walker at step t.

### Generating paths

We must edit your code a bit to have several independant paths.

```
walkers = 50 # Example for 50 walkers
path = []
steps = 60
for walker in range(walkers):
    walker_path=[0]
    position = 0
    for i in range(1, steps):
        move = np.random.randint(0, 2)
        if move == 0: position += -1
        else: position += 1
        walker_path.append(position)
    path.append(walker_path)
path = np.array(path)
```

As a sidenote, you could also use random.choice to randomly pick -1 or 1 directly, like so:

```
for i in range(1, steps):
    position += np.random.choice([-1, 1])
    walker_path.append(position)
```

From now, path is a 2D array : a row per walker path.

### Getting MSD at each step

To get all the MSD at every steps, we vary t from 1 to the number of steps.

You can do it inside a list comprehension in Python (and getting rid of your `calcMSD` function):

```
msd = [(path[:, i]**2).mean() for i in range(1, steps)] 
# you could also put range(1, len(path[0]))
```

### Result

Your function was not adapted to plot several walkers.

The proposed solution will give you something like this :

[image: MSD Proposed]

## What you want

I hope I understood what you truly wanted. I don't know how it's called but it can also be calculated in a list comprehension. Considering the path for a single walker :

```
not_msd = [(np.array([path[start:start+sep+1] for start in range(steps-sep)])**2).mean() for sep in range(1, steps)]
```

We go from start to start + step to get the difference between two positions that are `step` steps apart. We reproduce this operation, starting from 0 to the end of the list. Then we square the obtained list and take the mean.

We do that for all step size : 1 to the whole length.

Result :

[image: Not MSD proposed]

Comment: Thanks for a really clear response. I think I've misunderstood how to calculate the MSD. Say p(t) was position as a function of time. If I am understanding you correctly, at t = 3 you would calculate:

[ p(1)**2 + p(2)**2 + p(3)**2 ] / 3

I'll try to explain what I was attempting. I thought that you needed to calculate the difference in position between timepoints separated by some number t. So for t = 3 I thought it would be:

[ (p(3) - p(0))**2 + (p(4) - p(1))**2 + (p(5) - p(2))**2 + … (p(n) - p(n - 3))**2 ] / (the number of timepoints with 3 steps in between them.

Comment: My definition of MSD was **wrong**. I confused the mean of each step with the mean of all positions at a specific step. You need several walkers to have a MSD, else the MSD will simply be the square of your single path. I edited my answer.